# Clear Facebook session

Tags: android, facebook, session

Here I am trying to clear the values even if the session is true. So I am thinking of clearing the session. Below is what I am trying.

```
public boolean isSession() {
    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String access_token = sharedPrefs.getString("access_token", "x");
    Long expires = sharedPrefs.getLong("access_expires", -1);
    if (access_token != null && expires != -1) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }
    return facebook.isSessionValid();
```

How do I clear the session here so that it returns false when I check the following?

```
public void getID() {
    if (isSession()) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`facebook.setAccessExpires(-1);`

`facebook.setAccessToken(null);`

And then call `isSessionValid()`

Comment: I tried, at that point it reruns false. But what I am trying to do is, once this returns false,


public void getID() {



login();



}

public void login() {


if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {


facebook.authorize(this.activity, this.permissions,


new LoginDialogListener());


  }


 }

In this point, it is not asking me login again. Somehow it is taking the previously stored credentials

Answer (score 1):

```
com.facebook.Session session = com.facebook.Session.getActiveSession();
        if(session != null) session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

This work perfectly for me